# Mail.app performance after upgrade to Lion

Tags: mail.app

I am having some big issues with Mail.app after upgrade to Lion. Performance is horrible.

When i open a message, cpu usage grows up to 150% [See monitor activity screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ufzb7.png)

I already tried to repair permissions and remove all accounts to recreate it but it didn't make any difference.

I'm using 2 accounts with imap. The total messages on inbox is 12.000. Before upgrade, it was running fine.

Anyone experiencing this? Any ideas of what should i do?

Comment: This is curious. Have you tried rebuilding the database? I have almost 60 000 items in my mailbox.

Comment: Give it some time to optimize performance.

Comment: Have patience, the Lion's Mail has to upgrade the Mail database and it 12k items (and no knowledge of your hardware) that could take a while. Plus, Spotlight wants to upgrade too, the LaunchDB will want to upgrade, everybody wants to upgrade at the same time :)

Comment: @Randolph West Thank you! Rebuilding the database did the trick. It's running fine now.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

If you open the Mail's Activity window (keyboard shortcut: <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>), what does it show that justifies the 150% CPU figure?